# How to monitor/sniff Intents systemwide?

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like to monitor all the Intents running in an Android system.

I found an open-source application, IntentSniffer, in the following link.

https://www.isecpartners.com/tools/mobile-security/intent-sniffer.aspx

The main part of the application is the following code.

`ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE); 

List rti = am.getRecentTasks(1000, ActivityManager.RECENT_WITH_EXCLUDED); 

for(RecentTaskInfo c: rti) {

    Intent cur = c.baseIntent;

}`

However, the above code seems to get only baseIntent, not all Intents. So, I am wondering whether there is an way to monitor all the Intents in the system.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So, I am wondering whether there is an way to monitor all the Intents in the system.

Fortunately, no, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: (fixed) And in addition since 4.1.1 `baseIntent.getExtras()` will yield null.

Comment: `for obvious privacy and security reasons` could you be more specific? I understand an user app should not be able to do this. However I see no point why a superuser app on a dev or rooted phone should have this limitation. Or perhaps if no *app* should do this, lower level diagnostic tools still should?

Comment: @naxa: A ROM mod could offer it, and perhaps even a modified framework JAR (leaving the rest of the OS alone). It is not available in stock Android.